# Why the required attribute doesnt work inside the form

Tags: html, forms, validation

the required attribute does not work in this form. How can this be fixed?

```
 <form id="regform" action="PersonalDataAgreement.jsp" method="post" name="registration_form">
    <div class="register">
      <div class="input_field">
        <input type="text" placeholder="familyname" class="input" name="familyname" id="familyname" required>
      </div>
      <div class="input_field">
        <input type="text" placeholder="firstname" class="input" name="firstname"  id="firstname" required>
      </div>
      <div class="input_field">
        <input type="text" placeholder="secondname" class="input" name="secondname"  id="secondname" required>
      </div>
      <div class="btn"><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('regform').submit()">Register</a></div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: [The  placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 0):

Calling the form's `submit()` method bypasses the validation step.

Use a real submit button instead. Apply CSS to make it look the way you want.

```
<button>Register</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Submitting form from JS code ignores the required attribute. You can also validate input fields through JS code before submitting the form.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="regform" action="PersonalDataAgreement.jsp" method="post" name="registration_form">
        <div class="register">
          <div class="input_field">
            <input type="text" placeholder="familyname" class="input" name="familyname" id="familyname" required>
          </div>
          <div class="input_field">
            <input type="text" placeholder="firstname" class="input" name="firstname"  id="firstname" required>
          </div>
          <div class="input_field">
            <input type="text" placeholder="secondname" class="input" name="secondname"  id="secondname" required>
          </div>
          <div class="btn"><a href="#" onclick="handleSubmit(event)">Register</a></div>
        </div>
        </form>
        <script>
            function handleSubmit(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                familyName = document.getElementById('familyname');
                firstName = document.getElementById('firstname');
                secondName = document.getElementById('secondname');
                if (familyName.value === "" || firstName.value === "" || secondName.value === "") {
                        alert("Please fill the required fields")
                        //here you can validate inputs
                }else{
                    document.getElementById('regform').submit()
                }
                
            }
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Change your "register" button to:

```
 <div class="btn"><button>Register</button></div>
```

And it works fine.